# Why is this simple Java synchronized code block example giving me different output, depending on which object I lock on?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Ok, so I am trying to learn multi-threading. I am reading a book and I came across this example for synchronized code blocks:

```
class CallMe {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {

    String msg;
    CallMe target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller(CallMe target, String msg) {
        this.target = target;
        this.msg = msg;
        t = new Thread( this );
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() { 
        synchronized (target) {
            target.call(msg);
        }
    }
}

public class Scrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CallMe target = new CallMe();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller( target, "Hello");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller( target, "Synchronized" );
        Caller ob3 = new Caller( target, "World");

        try {
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following output from this:

```
[Hello]
[World]
[Synchronized]
```

Then, since I have done some tutorials online, I know that it is good style (or was told this) to create an instance of `Object` just for locking. So, I did this and the `Caller` class became:

```
class Caller implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    CallMe target;
    Thread t;

    private Object lock = new Object();

    public Caller(CallMe target, String msg) {
        this.target = target;
        this.msg = msg;
        t = new Thread( this );
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            target.call(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I was a little surprised when I got this as output:

```
[Synchronized[Hello[World]
]
]
```

Of course, this is output where interleaving has taken place and it is not correct. My question is why did this happen? I thought that making the lock `Object` would give me the same results. Why did it (or why would it) not give me the same output? I thought that creating the `Object` instance was good style and would work the same in this case, and to be honest I can't see why it would be different locking on "target" versus "lock". I guess what I mean to ask is, why does locking on one certain item in this case cause the program to be correct and locking on the other makes it wrong?

Comment: `synchronized` depends on the target object.

Comment: Yes, but what would make it different in this case?

Comment: I'm going to criticize this tutorial first by saying that a `Runnable` **should never start itself in a `Thread`** .

Comment: synchronized(lock) simply means that any other code wishing to use the lock will be made to wait. It won't keep anything not locked, or a different instance from being changed/called.

Comment: It's probably better to just synchronized the whole method where the critical stuff is happening rather than on a code block.

Comment: Each instance of `Caller` locks on a different instance of `lock`. I think you have to `synchronize` on shared instances.

Comment: The book is called "Java, The Complete Reference, 8th Edition", by Herbert Schlidt. Example taken directly from there.

Comment: Make the Object lock static.

Comment: @Chocobonstrife You should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of `Caller` locks on a different instance of `lock`. I think you have to `synchronize` on shared instances. Making the `lock` into a `static` member would share the same instance across all threads.

Comment: Say "static" instead of shared and I think you win this question. :)

Comment: @mttdbrd Don't make things `static` just so that you can share them. You can pass in the same argument if you need to.

Comment: Of course, but we've got a lot of threads synchronizing on a single object. Why pass it around and make spaghetti code? Probably begging for deadlock if it's just passed around.

Comment: @mttdbrd I don't see spaghetti. I see one instance field.

Comment: The important thing to take away is that it has to be the same instance across all threads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The code blocks are synchronized on one object in each thread that's being recreated with each new thread. I don't think I understand your comments here.

Comment: @mttdbrd When you create the `Runnable`, just pass in the lock object. Store it in an instance field and `synchronize` on it when needed. That is not spaghetti to me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see what you're saying. That works too.